# mockito spy object with annotated method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito

If I add an annotation over a method of mocked objet, the mock is disabled:

```
@Service
public class PurchaseService extends AbstractService {
    @Autowired
    private CheckoutService checkoutService;

    @EventAnnotation(EventTypeEnum.PRC_PRODUCT)
    public CheckoutResponse buy(String productId) {
        return checkoutService.buy(productId);
    }
}


@Service
public class CheckoutService extends AbstractService {
    public CheckoutResponse buy(ExecutionContext context, String productId) {
        .....
}
```

And the test:

```
@Autowired
@Spy
private UserService userService;

...

@Test
public void should_buy() {
    // Given
    String productId = "productId";
    Loyalty loyalty = new Loyalty(15, new Grade("1", "label", 10));

    when(catalogClient.findPromoProductForMember(DEFAULT_TENANT, productId, userId)).thenReturn(promoProduct);
    when(userService.getUserLoyalty(userId)).thenReturn(loyalty);

    // When
    CheckoutResponse result = purchaseService.buy(productId); // <---

    // Then
    assertThat(response).isNotNull();
    assertThat(result).isSameAs(response);
}
```

If I change `purchaseService.buy` by 
        `CheckoutResponse result = checkoutService.buy`, it works

Have a solution or get around?

Comment: Could you paste here all code of your test?

Comment: Don't inject the UserService into your test.  Just mock it.  This is a unit test, not an integration test.  You don't need to call anything real from the class you are testing.

Answer (score 2):

### Real Answer

Don't inject the UserService into your test. Just mock it. This is a unit test, not an integration test. You don't need to call anything real from the class you are testing.

### Irrational Answer

Don't use the Spy annotation.
Declare an @Before method and spy the injected object therein.
For example,

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;

@Autowired
private Smashy smasher;

@Before
public void preTestSetup()
{
    // I love to do unnecessary work! (be sure to include this comment).
    smasher = spy(smasher);
}
```

***Edit***
If either 1 or 2 in my comment below is true,
I believe you may need to either just mock the *Smashy* interface or do this:

```
@Before
public void preTestSetup()
{
    smasher = mock(Smashy.class); // replace the injected with a mock.

    doReturn(...; // setup the mocking behavior.
}
```

This is; however, just a variation of "Real Answer" above.

Consider this as well:

```
@Mock
private Smashy mockSmashy;

@Before
public void preTestSetup()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    doReturn(...; // setup the mocking behavior.
}
```

Comment: thanks ! I'll choose Irrational Answer, no choice :)  
and I have a problem "Smashy" is an interface and Autowired with spring : spy(smasher) throw error :  
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.app.rest.client.Smashy$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3611f45
Mockito can only mock visible & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list. 
Caused by: org.mockito.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file com/app/rest/client/Smashy$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3611f45$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$cdb8bdab 
And spy(SmachyImpl.class) throws : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to create mock instance of type 'SmashyImpl'   
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.app.rest.client.impl.SmashyImpl$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$6d90a1f3 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.app.rest.client.impl.SmashyImpl$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$6d90a1f3.<init>()

Comment: Sounds like one of these:
1. the name of the actual class that you are injecting is "SmashyImpl" and Mockito wants to use that name because Smashy is an Interface.
2. the actual class that you are injecting is final.

Comment: Pay attention.  You are injecting an object that implements the interface.  The type of the reference is an interface the type of the injected bean is a class.

Comment: @DwB sometimes the "irrational" option is required in order to spy/mock the real world responses as part of an integration test